# Generate PDF with pie chart -iText7

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, pie-chart, html2pdf

The obvious primary reason for using iText being , our company already have a license.

**Requirement**:
Generate a report that includes pie chart.
Our UX gave us a HTML, And I'm using [html2pdf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/html2pdf/3.0.5) plugin to generate pdf.
We're using [tlx-chart](https://github.com/anywhichway/tlx-chart) for its simplest code.

**Issue**:
PDF doesn't render/show piechart. No errors seen in logs.
HTML is being created perfectly (Althought iText conversion seems to be not so good), and When I load it with chromedriver as provided in KB article below, it renders overlapped 2 piecharts instead of 1.

So, This [knowledgebase](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/evaluating-js-with-pdfhtml) article from iText doesn't help.

- Infact, I've thought I cannot keep on updating chromedriver,selenium on prod server.
- I've to provide a loosely coupled (OS>PDF>PIE) to generate PDF.

Code Snippet:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(reportHtml, pdfWriter, new ConverterProperties());

"<tlx-chart id=\"mychart\" chart-type=\"PieChart\" chart-editable=\"true\" chart-columns=\"${['Element','Percentage']}\" chart-data=\"${${pieData}}\" </tlx-chart>"
```

Please Help!

Comment: The `HtmlConverter` only considers static contents and style information, nothing dynamically rendered, in particular nothing rendered by JavaScript components like tlx-chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is to embed piechart in PDF since JavaScript tags were not being rendered by iText library. And I resolved this in my case using jFreeChart.

- Generate an image using jFreechart and embed that image in HTML
- iText perfectly renders this as per HTML CSS
- For detailed explanation and code snippet on this [please visit here](https://medium.com/@SatyaRaj_PC/working-with-jfreechart-and-itextpdf-piechart-in-pdf-26c2d0646f51)
- An alternative way is also documented [here](https://medium.com/@SatyaRaj_PC/java-xchart-an-alternative-jfreechart-209ea68ace3b)

Answer (score 0):

Another option available is you can evaluate the javascript within the html and then convert that HTML to pdf.

Here it is explain very well -
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/evaluating-js-with-pdfhtml

Answer (score 0):

I use the webclient, where I call the url of the process or js with the graphics and then convert it to pdf.

I use google chars.

My code:

```
/*call de url */
    
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("https://gestaocomunidade.herokuapp.com/relatorioAdministracao/pdfImpressao?idAdministracao="
                    + idAdministracao + "&dataInicio=" + dataInicio + "&dataFim=" + dataFim);
    
/* Setup Source and target I/O streams */
ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
// You might need this configuration if HtmlUnit fails without it
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
String xml = page.asXml();
    
/* Setup converter properties. */
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setBaseUri("https://gestaocomunidade.herokuapp.com");
converterProperties.setCharset("UTF-8");
    
/* Call convert method */
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(xml, target, converterProperties);
```